# Angular2 response convert into object below an example

Tags: angular2-services

I m a new bie in Angular2. While trying to access services(Angular2) i could not able to convert into object of student.
Below is the code i m using it.

return this.http.post(this.url,student,{headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-type','application/json')}).subscribe(data => HERE)

```
         var student_info =  {
              studentid:  id,
              name:  name,
              address: address,
              stream: stream
            }
```

I want to convert return object into a `Student` object for which I have class is as below

```
{
      export class Student     
         studentid: number;    
         name: String;   
         address: String;  
}        stream: String;
```

Could not able to convert above data (Object into `Student`).
I want to access `Student` attributes e.g `Student.name` etc.

Comment: i have solved the issue by using a array which hold retrieved data.
e.g myVar = [];
And i m using it as .subscribe((data: any)=> this.mydata = data )
and defined iteratble to iterate.Anguar does really good by making object as the one we have fetched from API.
Thanks for the help Amit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` Observable operator like so:

```
return this.http.post(this.url,student,{headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-type','application/json')})
    .map(data => 
        return student_info =  {
            studentid:  data.id,
            name:  data.name,
            address: data.address,
            stream: data.stream
        });
```

It is exactly the same as Array.map, applying a function on each element of the Observable.

Comment: but it says that property id,name does not exist on type object for this part
return student_info =  {
            studentid:  data.id,
            name:  data.name,
            address: data.address,
            stream: data.stream
        });

Comment: That depends on the data that is stored in your response. Don't you return the `id`, `name`, `address` and `stream` in the `data` object? If not, then how are you supposed to create a `Student` instance using the data from the response?